# Ошибка NumberFormatException при чтении файла CSV

Tags: java

Существует файл [report.CSV](https://uploadfiles.io/o95d1).

Задача программы посчитать сколько раз встречается слово из колонки `К` и посчитать сумму чисел из колонки `R` по каждому слову из колонки `К`.

Вот программа:

```
public class CSVtestclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {    

        String FileName = "c:\\TestJava\\report.csv";    
        File file = new File(FileName);
        Map<String, WordInfo> wordInfoMap = new HashMap<>();    

        try(BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))){
            String s;
            String wordName;
            HashMap<String, int[]> stringIntegerHashMap = new HashMap<>();
            read.readLine();
            while( (s = read.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] next = s.split(";");
                wordName = next[10];
                if (stringIntegerHashMap.containsKey(wordName)) {
                    int[] ints = stringIntegerHashMap.get(wordName);
                    ints[0]++;
                    ints[1] += Integer.parseInt(next[17]);
                } else {
                    stringIntegerHashMap.put(wordName, new int[]{1, Integer.parseInt(next[17])});
                }
            }

            for (Map.Entry<String, int[]> pair: stringIntegerHashMap.entrySet()) {
                int[] value = pair.getValue();
                System.out.printf("%s zayavki: %d interakcii: %d%n", pair.getKey(), value[0], value[1]);
            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Во время выполнения программы выходит ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""0""
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:638)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
at CSVpack.CSVtestclass.main(CSVtestclass.java:31)
```

[image: картинка с ошибкой]

Где я ошибся?

Comment: укажите строку где выскакивает исплючение

Comment: вот скрин https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/12/2/d678748bb19c3c3affd9beb86259b6a6-full.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

public class CSVtestclass {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String FileName = "c:\\TestJava\\report.csv";

    File file = new File(FileName);
    Map<String, WordInfo> wordInfoMap = new HashMap<>();    

    try (BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String s;
        String wordName;
        HashMap<String, int[]> stringIntegerHashMap = new HashMap<>();
        read.readLine();
        while ((s = read.readLine()) != null) {
            try {
                String[] next = s.split(";");
                wordName = next[10];
                next[17] = next[17].replace("\"", "");
                if (stringIntegerHashMap.containsKey(wordName)) {
                    int[] ints = stringIntegerHashMap.get(wordName);
                    ints[0]++;
                    ints[1] += Integer.parseInt(next[17]);
                } else {
                    stringIntegerHashMap.put(wordName, new int[]{1, Integer.parseInt(next[17])});
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, int[]> pair : stringIntegerHashMap.entrySet()) {
            int[] value = pair.getValue();
            System.out.printf("%s zayavki: %d interakcii: %d%n", pair.getKey(), value[0], value[1]);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Есть несколько важных моментов...
1. Исключение летит из-за того, что 0 у вас записан не просто как 0, а как "0". Это нельзя распарсить. Кавычки придется убирать руками, если вы хотите , чтобы ве работало. 
2.В N-ной строке в ячейке, которую вы пытаетесь распарсить содержится просто текст. Тут задача совсем непосильная, сами решайте, что с этим текстом делать.
3. Парс - потенциально опасное место с точки зрения исключительных ситуаций. Посему настоятельно рекомендуется обрамлять такое блоками try-catch.

Итого, замену кавычек я добавил, блок try-catch тоже. В блоке обычный вывод в консоль сообщения с исключением, соответственно, при запуске увидите строку, текста, которую, разумеется, никак в цифры не превратишь, сами решите, что именно прописать в блоке try-catch уже в зависимости от бизнес-задачи.
Удачи

Comment: не понял, что значит этот код?

Comment: это ваш код только исправленный. замените его и все будет норм

Comment: Я в файле не вижу, что 0 записан в кавычках, где он эти кавычки находит?

Comment: дело в том, что он не просто 0 в кавычках берет, а все данные из файла закавычивает, используя точку с запятой в качестве разделителя. вы не забывайте, что фактически за самим документом стоит xml. для понимания ситуации вспомните документ exсel, где ячейку можно пометить, как текстовую, а можно как числовую.  а теперь представьте, что вы читаете только текстовые данные и ноль в этом контексте тоже является текстом, в итоге получаете закавыченный ноль. все на самом деле немного не так, но так проще для понимания

Comment: а вообще, если вы хотите парсить разного рода документы, сохранять данные в различных форматах, посмотрите в сторону apache POI. я давно пользуюсь и горя не знаю. для качественного форматирования документов там, конечно, придется писать много кода, зато на выходе этот документ отличить от сделанного руками невозможно в принципе. и на распарсивание любых форматов он заточен гораздо лучше , чем стандартные средства java. ам эти самые кавычки уже являются частью контекста, а не мозолят глаза

Answer (score 2):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""0""
```

Сообщает о том, что вы пытаетесь преобразовать "0" в число. Но какому числу соответствует "?

перед переводом строки в число удалите оттуда все лишние

```
string.replaceAll("\"", ""); - в вашем случае
string.replaceAll("\\D", ""); - для удаления всех символов (не чисел)
```

---

Конкретно вам в блоке else перед вложением в мапу (31 строка) надо выполнить команды :

```
String number = next[17].replaceAll("\"", "");
int value = Integer.parseInt(number);
```

либо короче:

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(next[17].replaceAll("\"", ""));
```

и положить это в мапу.

Comment: Виктор, могу попросить в моем коде указать конкретно что нужно ввести?  Простите за занудство, просто не очень понял

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan дополнил

Comment: Виктор, не распознает replaceall --   https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/12/2/c23953dafe7f659fcfd4f2eb02be0871-full.png

Comment: да, после replaceAll точка ненужна, закралась блин, моя ошибка =) Поправил в посте

Comment: Теперь другая ошибка-  https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/12/2/5f6aa2809904ff2d2d0bc80903295731-full.png

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan извиняюсь второй косяк, давно не пользовался этим методом. Ща пост обновлю.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69585/discussion-between-vaagn-akopyan-and-).

Comment: Ответил в чате, не помогло